# multiple matrices in c# xna phone app

Tags: c#, matrix, model, xna

I've created the beginnings of a windows phone app. It's a mix of two popular online tutorials

http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/simple-3d-animation
http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series1/Terrain_from_file.php

The code I've made is here
http://pastebin.com/5VusJpB0

I've added some code to catch the use of the accelerometer but it's all going a bit wrong! The code I've copied from the two examples have both declared world, view and projection matrices. One set for aircraft model in rbwhitakers code and the other set for the terrain from riemers code. I believe the matrices are the problem but I don't quite understand how they work. I only need one camera view so I need to lose a view matrix and it only needs one projection declaration right so I need to lose another projection matrix?. I'm guessing they should both share the same world but have different positions in that world. Can somebody help a noob out and see the problem?!

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track to solving this. Both the terrain and the model (and any other drawn item) should share the same view and projection matrices. Each item, however, should have it's own world matrix.

The world matrix represents the individual item's position and orientation relative to world space.

Think of the view matrix as the camera's position and orientation in the world. In actuality it is an inverse of that, but can be thought of as that for mind's eye conceptualizing.

The projection matrix is somewhat analogous with a lens attached to the camera (the view matrix) as it modifies the way the world is seen from the camera's perspective.

Just as when viewing a movie you are looking at many actors or props at any given moment (each with it's own position and orientation (world matrix) in the scene), you view them through a single camera at a time (shared view matrix) which is fitted with a single lens at a time(the projection matrix)

Comment: Got there in the end! Thanks for the reply Steve. Here's the code if it's any use to anyone http://pastebin.com/13508FYs